# Proof that: Number of faces in the Cartesian product of two convex polytope is sum of individual faces

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, polytopes, convex-geometry

We have two convex polytopes *C1* of *dim(m)* and *C2* of *dim(n)*, in *C1* we have *d1* dimensional face and in *C2* we have *d2* dimensional face. How can we prove that *C1* X *C2*(Cartesian product) has dimensional face *(d1+d2)*?

Comment: How are your polytopes defined, by half-spaces or as convex hulls?

Comment: By using Convex Hull